# Elegant creating of images in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to ask if there is a more elegant way to insert images to html with javascript without jQuery than:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                name = i + "_img";
                document.write("<img name=" + name + " />");
                img = document.images[name];
                img.src = i + ".png";
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Eventually I am gonna have there much more atributes and I want to avoid using < img /> as much as possible to make it more transparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create elements in JavaScript by using `document.createElement("tag")`. For example, `document.createElement("image")`. So you don't need to construct a string like you're doing. For some elements, such as an image, you can also just do `new Image()`. Keep in mind when you create an element in such a manner, it not yet part of the DOM. You must add it using `appendChild` or some other means.

Also, I would refrain from using `document.images[]` as I'm not sure that's entirely cross-browser friendly. I believe the standard practice is `document.getElementsByTagName("image")`, which returns an array you can iterate through.

```
var whereToAppend = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     var name = i + "_img";
     var img = new Image();
     img.src = i + ".png";
     whereToAppend.appendChild(img);
}
```